# Javascript select option application

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create the select application using Javascipt only. I got to know about this code on internet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select Options</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Choose your car</h2>
<hr>

Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
    <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="Maruti">Maruti</option>
</select>

<hr>

Choose Car Model
<select id="slct2" ></select>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function populate(s1,s2){
        var s1,s2;
        s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        s2 = document.getElementById(s2);

        if(s1.value=='Hyundai'){
            optionArray=['Please Select Car','i10','i20','Verna']
        } else
        if(s1.value=='Honda'){
            optionArray=['Please Select Car','Amaze','Jazz','City']
        } else
        if(s1.value=='Maruti'){
            optionArray=['Please Select Car','Swift','Dezire','Ciaze']
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
        var store = optionArray[i];
        var createNewEl = document.createElement('option');
        createNewEl.innerHTML = store;
        s2.appendChild(createNewEl);
        }

    }    

</script>
</html>
```

This is the full code I use now to write this apllication but I everytime I select option from car make ** and when I select another option fromcar make**, it does not delete the previous options from car model and the list gets increased so on everytime I select option from car make

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to import jQuery. Paste this between `<head>` tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your script is appending new values to end of the **select** list, so it have to remove all **old** values.

```
$("#slct2 option").remove();
```

I tested it and works fine for me. Here is full, working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Select Options</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Choose your car</h2>
<hr>

Choose Car Make:
<select id="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option>
    <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
    <option value="Maruti">Maruti</option>
</select>

<hr>

Choose Car Model
<select id="slct2"></select>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function populate(s1,s2){

        var s1,s2;
        s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        s2 = document.getElementById(s2);        

        $("#slct2 option").remove();

        if(s1.value=='Hyundai'){
            optionArray=['Please Select Car','i10','i20','Verna']
        } else
        if(s1.value=='Honda'){
            optionArray=['Please Select Car','Amaze','Jazz','City']
        } else
        if(s1.value=='Maruti'){
            optionArray=['Please Select Car','Swift','Dezire','Ciaze']
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < optionArray.length; i++) {
            var store = optionArray[i];
            var createNewEl = document.createElement('option');
            createNewEl.innerHTML = store;
            s2.appendChild(createNewEl);
        }
    }    

</script>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't want to use jQuery just replace this `$("#slct2 option").remove();` with this:

```
while (s2.firstChild) {
    s2.removeChild(s2.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Thanks 
It worked but are there any more methods besides the other two that you have provided because write now I am in my initial of learning Javascript and I think I partially understood the while statement. Is there something that we can with like **if** statement or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

`s2.appendChild(createNewEl);` adds to a list of whatever

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_node_appendchild

Comment: I also tried this `for..in` loop and did not use **append** in that, results were same. Any solution from your side ?